# OpenXML Set and Retrieve Custom Attributes

Tags: linq, openxml

I am successfully appending a custom attribute to a row node using the following method:

```
targetRow.SetAttribute(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.OpenXmlAttribute("Delete", null, "1"));
```

...but am unable to view the custom attribute using the following LINQ query:

```
Row target = sheetData.Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.ExtendedAttributes.ElementAt(0).Value=="1").First();
```

I've also tried using the 'GetAttribute' method in the above query, to no avail.

How should I be doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide xml? And what is `Custom Attributes`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code to get elements or attributes:

```
// get all elements with Delete="1" attribute
sheetData.Elements().First(elm => elm.Attribute("Delete").Value == "1")

//get first attribute of name Delete
sheetData.Elements().Attributes().First(atr => atr.Name == "Delete")
```

How to set attributes:

```
var s = "<t><a Delete=\"1\"/><a /></t>";    
var xml = XElement.Parse(s);
var atribute = xml.Elements().Attributes().First(atr => atr.Name == "Delete");

atribute.Value = "2";

//LinqPad specific call
xml.Dump();
```

Prints:

```
<t>
  <a Delete="2" />
  <a />
</t>
```